# Hierarchical Query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I have data like this:

[image: Data Table]

From the above table I am trying to write a SQL using connect by clause to get a hierarchy like this

```
      MAINCONTENT

       SPECIAL
        RIDGE
         SALESCONTENT

       ANOTHERONE
        RODGE
         SOMETHING ELSE
          ANOTHER
        ...
```

So far this SQL below is showing my only all the children of 'MAINCONTENT' but i want to do it without passing the parameter. Also this below one is not showing me the Children of Children, meaning its not doing recursive.

```
    select DISTINCT parent from  MYTABLE
    connect by prior CHILD = PARENT
    start with PARENT = 'MAINCONTENT';
```

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Barmar The link is for MySQL, it doesn't really show how to use `CONNECT BY`

Comment: Oops, sorry. I mistakenly remembered it as being more generic.

Comment: Anyway, you should show what you tried, so people can help you fix it. SO is not for getting other people to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be showing only part of the data in the spreadsheet, so I'm not sure if the below is 100% correct, but:

First get rid of indirect links (direct ones should cover the entire tree) and create extra entries for top-level records. Then apply hierarchical clause.

Try the below:

```
WITH mytable_normalized AS (
  SELECT parent, child
    FROM mytable
   WHERE direct_link = 'Y'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT null, parent
    FROM mytable
   MINUS
  SELECT null, child
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT lpad(' ', level*2) || child
  FROM mytable_normalized
CONNECT BY prior child = parent
 START WITH parent IS NULL;
```